BinaryObjects in StreamReceiver & generic types
I'm trying to understand what is the proper way of working with StreamReceiver's which are used with IgniteDataStreamer where keepBinary(true) is set. Consider this code:
IgniteDataStreamer<MyPojoKey, MyPojoEntity> streamer = ignite.dataStreamer(cacheName);
streamer.keepBinary(true);
streamer.receiver(new MyReceiver());

Now, the thing is - MyReceiver must implement StreamReceiver<MyPojoKey, MyPojoEntity>, but not StreamReceiver<BinaryObject, BinaryObject> - otherwise the code above won't compile. As the result, the receive method looks like that:
public class MyReceiver implements StreamReceiver<MyPojoKey, MyPojoEntity> {
  @Override
  void receive(IgniteCache<MyPojoKey, MyPojoEntity> cache,
             Collection<Map.Entry<MyPojoKey, MyPojoEntity>> entries) {
    // 
  }
}

Now, the key and the value that come in the entries collection are not MyPojoKey and MyPojoEntity! Since keepBinary was called above with true, they're BinaryObjectImpl's - where BinaryObjectImpl is an Ignite type - which is possible only due to Java's type erasure. I can cast them to proper BinaryObject of course and then work with them as such:
  void receive(IgniteCache<MyPojoKey, MyPojoEntity> cache,
             Collection<Map.Entry<MyPojoKey, MyPojoEntity>> entries) {
    entries.forEach(entry -> {
      // Notice I can't do "MyPojoEntity en = entry.getValue()" - that would throw ClassCastException
      BinaryObject binaryEntity = (BinaryObject)entry.getValue();

      // Notice unchecked cast to raw IgniteCache - can't compile it otherwise!
      ((IgniteCache)cache).put(key, binaryEntity);

    });
  }


The code above works as expected, although with those very dirty tricks with type erasure, to work around what effectively is java heap pollution. So it's quite a bit twisted, isn't it?
Sure thing, a simpler and safer workaround is probably making MyReceiver implement StreamReceiver<BinaryObject, BinaryObject>, and then use the raw type of IgniteDataStreamer:
 // ...
 ((IgniteDataStreamer)streamer).receiver(new MyReceiver()); // Cast to raw IgniteDataStreamer
 // ... and where MyReceiver now implements StreamReceiver<BinaryObject, BinaryObject> 

, in which case at least MyReceiver can be implemented as properly strongly typed. But still it looks like a dirty hack, so I suspect it's me doing something wrong there?

I agree that this is confusing, but the solution is actually pretty simple: you specify the BinaryObject in the data streamer:
IgniteDataStreamer<BinaryObject, BinaryObject> streamer = ignite.dataStreamer(cacheName);
streamer.keepBinary(true);
streamer.receiver(new MyReceiver());


Thanks, but then I can't send the original objects. I.e. I can't do this then: "streamer.addData(new MyPojoKey(...), new MyPojoEntity(...))" - it won't compile.
